# Ember App: Looking for a workaround for Safari bug that ignores the '#' in my url on https redirects by Cloudfront

Tags: ember.js, safari, amazon-cloudfront

**UPDATE 2:**

I found the reason, but not a solution yet. This has to do with how safari browsers deal with the '#' when Cloudfront redirects HTTP to HTTPS. Safari ignores the hashtag, and apparently this is a bug that's existed in Safari for years. I'm not 100% sure this is my issue, but it seems to be. Still looking for a solution.

**END UPDATE 2**

For some reason I'm having trouble figuring out, Safari browsers (mobile and desktop) act differently from Chrome and Firefox when I refresh a page or try to access a route directly on my app.

I have a playlists route:

```js
Router.map(function() {
    ...
    this.resource("playlists", function () {});
    ...
});
```

I can hit the playlists route directly with rooturl.com/playlists on Chrome and Firefox and in the console logs, I see this:

`Attempting URL transition to /playlists`

When I try to hit the playlists route directly in Safari, I see this:

`Attempting URL transition to /`

Another strange thing is that when I use my localhost the transition is correct on all browsers including safari (mobile and desktop). This makes me think it has something to do with the production environment. I'm using AWS S3 and Cloudfront, but I'm not fully sure that has anything to do with this.

I can provide more information here if asked.

**UPDATE:**

When I use the fragment (followed by a '#') in the url, safari redirects correctly. So this redirects correctly:

`example.com/#/playlists`

But this does not:

`example.com/playlists`

Again, this problem only occurs in production, on AWS S3/Cloudfront. On localhost, Safari works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was fixed by making sure the protocol is not switched from https to http at any point. Specifically, S3 was issuing a redirect over http while the original request was over https. This leads to Safari stripping the request from any (potentially) sensitive data.

Fixed it by adding https to our S3 redirect setup.